# unable to see the managed property in Build Your Query SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-property, managed-property, people-search, crawled-property

I am working in SP2013 , created a new custom user profile property with Type Booolen. once search people crawl is completed i can able to see that field in Crawled properties.After that i created a managed property in Search service application at Central Admin and mapped the property. again ran the full search people crawl once completed .i went to the site and try to query the values but unable to see the managed property field in the property filter as per  below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Go to SharePoint admin center > search > Manage Search Schema > Managed Properties, then click property name to view the details. In the Main characteristics section, make sure Searchable, Queryable, Retrievable are checked.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i did every thing correctly. but still it is not working.

Comment: check this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dep365/custom-managed-property-not-showing-up-in-the/6174ad2d-9874-448d-845b-27cbd6145f96

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that for the Managed Property, under the Advanced button, you select the PeopleIdx. Otherwise the field will not be associated with People.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer , i tried but still i am unable to see the Managed Property.

Comment: After making the change did you do a Full Crawl of the User Profiles (sps3)? Also, these properties should be defined in the SSA, they usually don't work in a Site or Site Collection.